# In or of ? looking for the right word/preposition

Tags: prepositions

I am looking for the correct preposition in the following sentence:

> You can actively recruit them for your cause **of/in** overthrowing the empire and the lord ruler.

Comment: Do you know the difference between 'off' and 'of'?

Answer (score 1):

Q. **I am looking for the correct preposition in the following sentence:**

You can actively recruit them for your cause of/in overthrowing the empire and the lord ruler.

I would suggest that the correct preposition is **to** "(used with an infinitive to express use or purpose)":

---

There is a difference in meaning . **In** denotes that you/they/that is "part of something", whilst **of** denotes "belonging to something"

**in preposition (PART)**: forming a part of something:

He used to be the lead singer in a rock band.

CED In

**of preposition (POSSESSION)**; to show possession, belonging, or origin:

employees of the company

CED Of

---

**You can actively recruit them for your cause of/in overthrowing the empire and the lord ruler**

I would personally re write your sentence as

***You can recruit them to defeat the Empire*** or  ***You can recruit them to overthrow the Lord Ruler.*** (remove from power)

Presumably the Empire and the lord Ruler are inherently linked so to defeat one automatically defeats the other.

actively recruit, in this case recruiting is a positive action and not passive (you have not posted adverts in the "Empire times" and are waiting for C.V.'s  therefore the use of actively is redundant.

cause = idea in this case but you have stated your objective "to overthrow the Empire" therefore cause is not required. Alternatively you could write **"You can recruit them to your cause"** (which is to over throw the Empire).

P.S. Names need capitalisation

**to: preposition**: used with an infinitive to express use or purpose:

This tool is used to make holes in leather.

CED [to](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/to)